# Push value to html and grab again from JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to assign a value to hidden input then grab that value from next section of javascript using input id. So it will alert the value as per hidden input value which assigned from the first section of javascript. However, it looks not useful this is important for my current task. I have to push value to HTML then get it back again in javascript variable. Let me know if you have any solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Just test</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.18/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
<script>
    var myVal = "some string";
    $("#foo").val(myVal);
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="foo" id="foo" value="">


<script>
    var doo = "";
    doo = $(this).find("#foo").val();
    if (doo != "") {
        alert(doo);
    }else{
        alert("doo is null");
    }
</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you let me know, why you are using 2 different sections of the javascript?Is it on different pages?

Comment: You'll have to wait until the `input` element is added to the DOM before you can access it. The code in the first `script` element doesn't do that.

Comment: Why are you splitting your code in 2 parts in the same page ?

Comment: Input with id `foo` should be before the 1st `script` tag. Also, in the second `script` what is `$(this)` referring to?

Comment: It's on the same page but I cant use it in single JS. its mandatory to use two different section of JS. Coz i am in complex page design that's why

Comment: Both your scripts executes at page load. So what is the meaning of setting the hidden value and getting it by reading the hidden field?

Comment: No, both scripts should not execute on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$(document).ready()` method which waits until all DOM elements are rendered. Then executes the JS code. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Just test</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.18/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            var myVal = "some string";
             $("#foo").val(myVal);
          });
             
        </script>

        <input type="hidden" name="foo" id="foo" value="">


        <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            var doo = "";
            doo = $(this).find("#foo").val();
            if (doo != "") {
                alert(doo);
            }else{
                alert("doo is null");
            }
            
          });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) of the Web API allows us to reference any and all form elements very easily:

**Example**

```
 /* Find the first form of a page without knowing it's .class or #id */

   // HTMLFormControlsCollection        // Common way
   var form = document.forms[0];        var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
```

### Demo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Just test</title>


</head>

<body>

  <form id='A'>
    <input id="X" name="X">
    <output id='Y' name='Y'></output>
    <input id='Z' name='Z' type='hidden'>
  </form>



  <script>
    var F = document.forms.A;

    F.oninput = function() {
      var X = F.X.value;
      var Y = F.Y;
      var Z = F.Z;
      Y.value = X;
      Z.value = X;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```